# Feature Extraction and higher sensitivity

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-extraction

When conducting feature extraction (PCA and LDA) on the WBCD dataset followed by logistic regression, I get an improved sensitivity but varying accuracies. I have been trying to find literature that can explain/ has looked into how feature extraction can improve a classifiers sensitivity, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Can you link to the dataset or describe what it contains? That will help people to give better answers. See this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/548/feature-extraction-technique-summarizing-a-sequence-of-data) for some links.

Comment: I am using the Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set. It contains 569 cases of either malignant or benign tumors, described with 30 features. Link: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+(Diagnostic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature extraction reduces the dimensionality of the data. This is usually done to create a smaller system (to reduce computational expense) and/or lessen noise (to get a clearer signal).

A concise introduction is given in *Introduction to Statistical Learning* (available [here](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~dias/Intoduction%20to%20Statistical%20Learning.pdf)) on Unsupervised Learning (p.373), which is I think what you are looking for.

Take the example of PCA. From *Introduction to Statistical Learning*:

> When faced with a large set of correlated variables, principal
>   components allow us to summarize this set with a smaller number of
>   representative variables that collectively explain most of the
>   variability in the original set. The principal component directions
>   are presented in Section 6.3.1 as directions in feature space along
>   which the original data are highly variable. These directions also
>   define lines and subspaces that are as close as possible to the data
>   cloud. To perform principal components regression, we simply use
>   principal components as predictors in a regression model in place of
>   the original larger set of variables.
>
> Principal component analysis (PCA) refers to the process by which
>   principal components are computed, and the subsequent use of these
>   components in understanding the data. PCA is an unsupervised approach,
>   since it involves only a set of features X1, X2,...,Xp, and no
>   associated response Y. Apart from producing derived variables for use
>   in supervised learning problems, PCA also serves as a tool for data
>   visualization (visualization of the observations or visualization of
>   the variables). We now discuss PCA in greater detail, focusing on the
>   use of PCA as a tool for unsupervised data exploration, in keeping
>   with the topic of this chapter.

My go-to resource is *Elements of Statistical Learning* (that is freely available [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)). Page 534 onwards has a detailed discussion of PCA, applying it to hand-writing to make the problem more tractable.